# QML text scroll

Tags: c++, qt, webview, qml

I am using C++ and QML to create a nice interface.
I would like to have a "console view", where plenty to text is printed through time.
However, when the text of a text item or webview content grows, the view does not "scroll down".

How can I make the text on the bottom of the text/webview item always stay visible ?

I have tried playing with flickable and the_webview.evaluateJavaScript + window.scrollTo , but I could not get them to do what I want.
This seems a fairly simple piece of UI, but I am having serious troubles to do it with QML.

Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

funkybro answers inspired my final solution:

```
function scroll_to_bottom() {
    flickabe_item.contentY = 
        Math.max(0, webview_item.height - flickabe_item.height);
    return;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Yeah I'd use a `Flickable` containing a `Text` object.  Whenever you add text to the `Text`, check its `paintedHeight`, and adjust the `Flickable`'s `contentY` if it's got any bigger.

Comment: This inspired my final solution:

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should consider using a `ListView` and have the messages as items in the view. Then you could use `ListView::positionViewAtEnd`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was to vertically flip both the content and Flickable. This way the text ends the right way up and is naturally anchored to the bottom of the flickable area.

It might be more efficient too since the transform is handled by OpenGL behind the scenes.

```
Flickable {
    id: flick
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentHeight: text.height
    Text {
        id: text
        width: parent.width
        transform: Scale { yScale: -1; origin.y: text.height/2 }
    }

    transform: Scale { yScale: -1; origin.y: flick.height/2 }
}
```